# Binding data not working in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to generate html using .enter method.

I have the following code:

```
alert(d3.select(".ul_class").length);
d3.select(".ul_class").data([4, 8, 15]).enter().append("li").text("hello");
```

The first alert displays "1", so de object is correctly selected. The second line does not append "li" elements inside my DOM object.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create a (empty) selection of `li` elements first:

```
d3.select(".ul_class")
  .selectAll('li') // <--
  .data([4, 8, 15]).enter().append("li").text("hello");
```

Then you bind the data to that empty selection, which will generate placeholders in the selection for the new data.

So you are basically saying:

*"Select all `li` elements and bind the data `[4, 8, 15]` to them. For all data items that are not bound yet, create a new `li` element."*

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8QgP/)